# Erlang Crash Dump is being written to: erl_crash.dump...done

Tags: intellij-idea, erlang

So I just started learning some basic Erlang. I am working on IntelliJ Idea. I wrote a basic function to add two numbers:

```
-module(easy).
-author("var").

%% API
-export([add/2]).

add(X, Y) ->
  X + Y.
```

However when I run it I am getting the following error:

```
{"init terminating in do_boot",{{badmatch,{error,{1,erl_parse,["syntax error before: ","','"]}}},[{init,start_it,1,[]},{init,start_em,1,[]}]}}

Crash dump is being written to: erl_crash.dump...done
init terminating in do_boot ()
```

I can't seem to figure out exactly why this happening. Is it to do with the Run config for Idea?

Comment: I have just tested the code locally, works perfectly. Issue must be relating to environment/config. Sorry can't help further.

Comment: Yeah I think there is some issue with my config/environment. Trying to figure that our. Thanks though!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not sure how you execute the code. Try to follow these steps.

Create the file containing the source code, in this case `easy.erl`, which you already have:

```
[g@somecomp:~/test]$ cat easy.erl 
-module(easy).
-author("var").

%% API
-export([add/2]).

add(X, Y) ->
    X + Y.
```

Now compile the module:

```
[g@somecomp:~/test]$ erlc easy.erl
```

Start Erlang and load it from the shell:

```
[g@somecomp:~/test]$ erl
Erlang/OTP 18 [erts-7.2.1] [source] [64-bit] [smp:4:4] [async-threads:10] [hipe] [kernel-poll:false]

Eshell V7.2.1  (abort with ^G)
1> l(easy).
{module,easy}
```

In the shell execute the function and close Erlang:

```
2> easy:add(1,2).
3
3> q().
ok
4> [g@somecomp:~/test]$
```

Alternatively, you can execute it directly from the shell (`bash`, `csh`) but in that case you must print out the return value explicitly:

```
[g@somecomp:~/test]$ erlc easy.erl
[g@somecomp:~/test]$ erl -noshell -eval 'io:format("~p~n", [easy:add(1,2)])' -s init stop
3
[g@somecomp:~/test]$
```